# Rails devise - error on update when resetting the password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have this controller code:

```
  def update

    super
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html{redirect_to session[:redirect_to]}
    end
  end
```

My class inherits from devise Passwords like this:

```
class Mobile::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
```

and I get this error:

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Mobile::PasswordsController#update

    Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. 
Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. 
Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so 
if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like 
"redirect_to(...) and return".
```

Any idea what to do? I know its the redirects, but I am not sure how to make them right.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `update` method](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb) of the Devise gem already has a redirect. Then you call your redirect and this causes the error. If you want to do a custom redirect you need to override a Devise method without a `super` call like this:

```ruby
def update
    self.resource = resource_class.reset_password_by_token(params[resource_name])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      flash_message = resource.active_for_authentication? ? :updated : :updated_not_active
      set_flash_message(:notice, flash_message) if is_navigational_format?
      sign_in(resource_name, resource)
      respond_with resource, :location => #your_path_on_success
    else
      flash[:error] = resource.errors.full_messages
      redirect_to #your_path_on_failure
    end
  end
```

Comment: thank you. It is hard to tell if that worked because I got this kind of an error after I tried the code: NoMethodError (undefined method `active_agency_id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:7:in `show'

Comment: @ArcaneRaine it looks like this:       unless current_user.active_agency_id.blank? && current_user.active_advertiser_id.blank?

Comment: So its some sort of a null pointer problem, but I am not sure why that becomes an issue? Is the user object not set where it needs to be set?

Comment: It is really like this:     if signed_in?
      unless current_user.active_agency_id.blank? && current_user.active_advertiser_id.blank?

Comment: So the system thinks the user is signed in, but when it tries to use the current_user object, it starts to run into problems.

Comment: By the way, I saw you are from Ukraine. I am too :) Where in Ukraine are you? Do you like soccer? :) I like Chernomorets :)

Comment: Rules said this is not a good place for a chatting, but from Simferopol, and I'am cheering for Bayern